# Informix dbserver connections in sqlhosts via perl

Tags: perl, informix

I want to add a new Informix sever entry into sqlhosts, but I'm not quite sure how it will impact the existing connection.

Currently sqlhosts contains only one server entry...

```
 dbserver       onsoctcp    111.111.111.20      7101
```

The database handle is created within an existing perl module (db is a database on the server)...

```
my $dsn = "DBI:Informix:db";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"user","password");
```

Notice that "dbserver" is never referenced.

I want to add a test server to sqlhosts. Something like this...

```
 dbserver       onsoctcp    111.111.111.20      7101
 dbserver_test  onsoctcp    111.111.111.21      7101
```

With only one entry in sqlhosts, everything has been working fine. But my connection never references the server name in sqlhosts.

So, my question(s)...

Does Informix just try to use the only one available?

Will adding a second server entry in sqlhosts force me to include the server name in the connection string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Informix client uses environment variables to resolve hosts and other configuration; check that `INFORMIXDIR` is set to the path where Informix CSDK is installed (I assume it is), and set `INFORMIXSERVER` to point to the new entry in `sqlhosts`. See [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_266.htm?lang=en) in IBM knowledge base.

Alternatively, use `db@server` data source format:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Informix:db@server", "user", "password");
```

Comment: BINGO! Sometimes I don't like ENV variables ;) Just for the record...I found that when there are two identical dbsever names in `sqlhosts`, the first on wins.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a permissions issue? From the documentation:

> Note that you might also be able to connect to other databases not
>   listed by DBI->data_sources using other notations to identify the
>   database. For example, you can connect to "dbase@server" if "server"
>   appears in the sqlhosts file and the database "dbase" exists on the
>   server and the server is up and you have permission to use both the
>   server and the database on the server and so on. Also, you might not
>   be able to connect to every one of the databases listed if you have
>   not been given at least connect permission on the database. However,
>   the databases listed by the DBI->data_sources method certainly exist,
>   and it is legitimate to try connecting to those sources.

http://search.cpan.org/~johnl/DBD-Informix-2013.0521/Informix.pm

Comment: The grants for user/pass have all been verified and work fine using dbaccess and server studio. Just seems odd that Informix, and all it's quirks, would use the only sqlhosts entry when there isn't one specified when creating the dns and the dbh.